# Check if query value is empty in NextJS using path parameter

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm currently looking for a way wherein I would be able to know if the query value is empty.

I'm doing it using the path parameter method. I have the file `pages/search/[variable1].js`

Here is my code:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

const Variable= () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { variable1 } = router.query
  console.log(variable1);
}
```

For example, I'm accessing `localhost:3000/search/abc`, the console would display `abc`. If I access it through `localhost:3000/search/`, the console does not display anything. What could be the possible condition so that I can check if `variable1` is empty? I tried doing ternary operator `variable1? console.log("not empty") : console.log("empty")` but I still don't see `empty` in the console.

Comment: Do you have another page defined at pages/search/index.js?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus None. Also, I just realized it redirects to 404.js which is pages/404.js. Does having pages/search/index.js result to a different result?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have page defined under `pages/search/index.js` but only `pages/search/[variable1].js` this means that your page [variable1].js will never catch `/search` route and will never show what you are expecting.

You have 2 options here:

1. change your page definition to catch all routes under search, so you would change path to `pages/search/[...variable1].js` which would also catch search index route(/search)
2. to simply create page under `pages/search/index.js` and use query params to catch search variable

Answer (score 1):

To access `localhost:3000/search`, you need to have `index.js` folder in the relevant path.

The expectation of the `localhost:3000/search/[veriable1].js` folder is that it expects a query after the search. So `localhost:3000/search` and `localhost:3000/search/_example_` are not the same page and they cannot access queries through each other.